# How to add user consent using UserMessagingPlatform

Tags: ios, swift, admob, apptrackingtransparency, user-messaging-platform

I have a few questions about Google's `UserMessagingPlatform`.

**Resources**

1. [Mobile Ads SDK - Guides](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start)
2. [Mobile Ads SDK - User Privacy](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy)
3. [Mobile Ads SDK - Reference](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/api/reference/Classes)
4. [EU User Consent Policy](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7666366?visit_id=638225505328153305-1122027354&hl=en&ref_topic=9008168&rd=1)
5. [Unity - Implementing Data Privacy](https://docs.unity.com/ads/en/manual/ImplementingDataPrivacy)

**Related questions**

1. [How to implement UMP SDK correctly for EU consent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351543/how-to-implement-ump-sdk-correctly-for-eu-consent)
2. [Google user messaging platform and objective c to swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618415/google-user-messaging-platform-and-objective-c-to-swift)

.

```
func requestConsentInfoUpdate(in vc: UIViewController, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    let parameters = UMPRequestParameters()
    parameters.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = false
    
    UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
        with: parameters,
        completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
            if error != nil {
                // handle error
            } else {
                if UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.formStatus == UMPFormStatus.available {
                    // if it is avaiable (and required) i load the form
                    self?.loadForm(in: vc, completion: completion)
                } else if UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.formStatus == UMPFormStatus.unknown {
                    // docs suggest to request another update
                    self?.requestConsentInfoUpdate(in: vc, completion: completion)
                } else {
                    completion?()
                }
            }
        })
}
```

This function gets called when the first `ViewController` is presented, takes as parameters the `vc` itself, which will present the form, and a `completion`, since I wanna wait for all the privacy stuff before calling `GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start()` and requesting ads.

**1. How do I handle the under age flag?**

Should I ask the user his age before presenting the form? Or should I just assume that the user is not a minor, like most apps do, and keep `tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = false` ?

**2. Infinite recursion?**

By docs, from [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy/api/reference/Enums/UMPFormStatus):

> UMPFormStatusUnknown: Whether a consent form is available is unknown. An update should be requested using requestConsentInfoUpdateWithParameters:completionHandler.

Maybe it's a stupid question, since if the docs advice for it then it should be safe, but could this implementation potentially cause infinite recursion?

```
private func loadForm(in vc: UIViewController, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    UMPConsentForm.load(completionHandler: { [weak self] form, loadError in
        if loadError != nil {
            // handle error
        } else {
            if UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == UMPConsentStatus.required {
                self?.present(form: form, in: vc, completion: completion)
            } else {
                completion?()
            }
        }
    })
}

private func present(form: UMPConsentForm?, in vc: UIViewController, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    form?.present(
        from: vc,
        completionHandler: { [weak self] _ in
            if UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == UMPConsentStatus.obtained {      
                GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
                completion?()
            }
        })
}
```

Here the form is loaded and presented.

**3. Where to pass consensus for mediation partners?**

If I understood correctly, UMP pass to its network all the privacy settings under the hood for me once the consensus is obtained. This is just for Google ads, what if I want to use mediation and present also Unity ads, for example? [Unity docs](https://docs.unity.com/ads/en/manual/GDPRCompliance#iOS_(Objective-C)) explain how, for GDPR consent for example:

```
let gdprMetaData = UADSMetaData()
gdprMetaData.set("gdpr.consent", value: true)
gdprMetaData.commit()
```

My question is where should I call this though. From my understanding, `UMPConsentStatus.obtained` means just that the the user set his preferences, not necessarily that he agreed to targeted advertising.

Comment: I've mostly answered question #3 on https://stackoverflow.com/a/77657427/2149955 You are right that as far as I can tell UMP doesn't provide a way out-of-the-box to read details of the consent status other than if the form was completed or not. You (or the Unity ads sdk) would need to read the TC or AC string in order to fetch the user's preferences that the UMP has written. I don't think UMP offers any utility out of the box to read it. I think Unity is in the AC string, but you have to read it and forward it yourself.